# Pseudo-streaming in Flash - Apache and httpd.conf Setup?

Tags: wordpress, apache, flash, video-streaming, jwplayer

I installed and setup JW Player 6 plugin to my wordpress. I am using licensed mod. Anyway If I choose rendering mode:"Flash" i can't skip to time. I installed and activated Apache module h264_streaming and restart apache server, but nothing changed.

Render Mode : "HTML5" is fine but i dont want to use html5. because video is loading slowly , i can skip to time in html5 but skip time is slow too in html5.

Comment: If you are rendering in html5 mode, you don't need pseudo streaming. Do you have an example of how it is running slow?

Comment: In flash mode video is loading very fast and i can skip to wherever i want in loaded part but not skip to time in unloaded part.And it is very fast too. In flash mode video is loading very slowly(when i stop, loading fast , i dont know how this happens) and when i skip to any loaded part.If it is loaded Still waiting for a bit so i think html5 is not fluent.

Comment: Please provide an example so I can see what you are talking about here.